# How do I annotate multiple reverse fields with filters and all?

Tags: django, orm, aggregate

I have "Product", "OrderItem" and "Stock". I would like the fastest query to determine the stock on hand and the total order quantity for each "Product".

I assumed it would be done like this:

```py
qs = (
    Product.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            "stock",
            queryset=Stock.objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now()),
        ),
        Prefetch("ordered_items", queryset=OrderItem.objects.all(),),
    )
    .annotate(
        total_on_hand=Sum("stock__quantity"),
        total_allocated=Sum("ordered_items__quantity_ordered"),
    )
    .order_by("id")
)
```

The above returns results, but the SQL doesn't include my "timestamp__lte" filter shown above. This invalidates the data.